# Border is cutting off when using border-radius?

Tags: html, css, border

I have an image which has a 5px border around it and I wanted to round the corners of both the image and the border, but in webkit the image remained rectangular whereas the corners of the border were rounded. As a result, the image overlapped the border and created what looks like a gap between the lines of the border at each corner.

I'd like it to look like this http://jsfiddle.net/rmi14/HWDtx/19/, but on webkit, the white background is rectangular and ends up overlapping some of the light blue border and cutting it off.

Comment: I think you forgot the image HTML in that fiddle. Same goes for any CSS applied to the image. Please update it accordingly. Or are we talking about a background-image to the `<div>`?

Comment: please show us the exact demo code of yours...

Answer (score 45):

You have to use the `overflow` property for your `div` as it is showed in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HWDtx/66/)

```
div {
    max-height: 400px;
    max-width: 200px;
    margin: 50px 150px;
    background-color: white;
    border: 5px solid #66CCFF;
    border-radius: 30px;
    -moz-border-radius: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

because the content angles overflows the rounded borders of the container angles

you can use:

```
border-radius: ...
overflow: hidden; /*add this*/
```

to cut off the angles of the content that overflows